# Difference eslint between 'prettier/vue' and '@vue/prettier'

Tags: vue.js, prettier, typescript-eslint, prettier-eslint, eslint-config-vue

Lately I was working on a vue3/vite + ts project and wanted to add eslint and prettier, but I'm getting confused what settings I should use in the eslint file(section "extends") and/or how to spell them. If I look at the official eslint [vue homepage](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#faq), they write the prettier stuff like the not commented out lines(picture below).But if I look at the [official eslint-config-typescript page](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-config-typescript) they write it like the commented out lines(picture below).
And if I google I find both examples in projects. So my question is:

Is there any difference between the writing?
Or do they do the same and it doesn't matter which one I take?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about vue3/vite + ts, but I see here 2 moments:

1. Usage of `@`. It is likely to be related to webpack (I believe you use vue-cli). It usually means something like that: `resolve: {alias: {'@': path.resolve('src')}},` So, `@` is just an alias for some path in your system, usually root/source folder for your project. You can find the exact path in `webpack.config.js`.
2. `vue/prettier` vs `prettier/vue`. Just location of the package. You either take `prettier` bundled with vue or a standalone `prettier` package that contains some custom/adopted version for vue. They are likely to be pretty much the same, check their package.json files for versions.

Comment: okay that would explain why the endresult is the same. Where can I find these oackage.json files? Do u mean the package.json file from my project?

Comment: no, I mean package.json files inside prettier/ and vue/ in node_modules folder - they have package.json too. For example, in my current project I have vue/ folder and in its package.json I can find `"prettier": "^1.18.2"` - it means that vue uses as its devdependancy prettier version 1.18.2